# What is the alternate to xeditable plugin in angularjs for editing input fields?

Tags: angularjs

For editing the input fields Iam using xeditable plugin.I want to know the alternate way for editing input fields rather than using xeditable plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same requirement for my project and i used [angular-editable-text](https://github.com/GabiGrin/angular-editable-text)

You can find the demo [here](http://gabigrin.github.io/angular-editable-text/)